# Isomorphism between $\Omega_{hor}^{k}\left(P\right)$ and $\Omega^{k}\left(M\right)$

Tags: differential-forms, principal-bundles, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $\pi\colon{P}\to{M}$ be a principal $G$-bundle and $\Omega_{hor}^{k}\left(P,\mathfrak{g}\right)$ the space of $\mathfrak{g}$-valued *horizontal*${}^*$ differential forms. Given a global section $s\in\Gamma\left(P\right)$, does the pullback of $s$ *define an isomorphism* between $\Omega_{hor}^{k}\left(P,\mathfrak{g}\right)$ and $\Omega^{k}\left(M,\mathfrak{g}\right)$ ? That is, is the map:
$$\Omega_{hor}^{k}\left(P,\mathfrak{g}\right)\ni\omega\mapsto{s^*}\omega\in\Omega^{k}\left(M,\mathfrak{g}\right)$$
an (vector bundle) isomorphism?

Intuitively, I expect the answer to be "yes". If this is the case, can you please provide a sketch of a proof?

---

$*$ Horizontal forms are, by definitionn, those that are identically zero when at least one of their arguments belongs in $T^{v}P=:\ker{\pi_*}$

Comment: If I am not wrong: if $P$ admits a global section then it is the trivial $G$-principal bundle on $M$!

Comment: I think that's right, but would it imply that this isomorphism exists?

Comment: I think this is not true even for flat bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. It's possible to have $s^* \omega = 0$ without $\omega$ being zero (say, start with any non-zero horizontal form and then multiply it by a bump function which is zero around the image of the section $s$).

The correct statement goes as follows. Consider $\Omega^k_\text{bas}(P, \mathfrak{g})$ to be the *basic* forms, i.e. horizontal forms which satisfy $R_g^* \alpha = \text{Ad}_{g^{-1}} \alpha$ for all $g \in G$, where $R_g : P \to P$ is translation by $g$. You can show that the pullback via $\pi : P \to M$ of a form in $\Omega^k(M, \mathfrak{g})$ in fact gives you a basic form, so that you have a map

$$ \pi^{*} : \Omega^k(M, \mathfrak{g}) \to \Omega^k_\text{bas}(P, \mathfrak{g})$$

and *this* map is an isomorphism. The proof is pretty straightforward, but for a sketch see proposition 2.49 in page 26 of [these](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~crain101/DG-2016/chapter2.pdf) notes.

Comment: I thought a basic form should be invariant -- as opposed to equivariant -- upon pullback by right translations. The map of pullback by the projection completely ignores the vertical component along the fiber, which is why it yields an invariant (basic) form on the bundle.